# how to make multiselecte dropdown field in flask?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am trying to make a multiselecte dropdown field with clear button in flask like this.

[image]

I have tried this but not working the way I want

```
type = SelectMultipleField("Type",choices=[("None", "None"), ("one", "one"), ("two", "two"), ("three", "three")], default=[('None', 'None')]
```

but I am getting like this, getting all choices at once without dropdown option

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue once, Better send the list of choices in your templete and run loop in option tag like this

```
<option value="None" selected>None</option>
{% for row in vin %}
<option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code comes from the way you have defined the choices. The `SelectMultipleField` field requires the choices to be defined as a list of tuples. Like this :

```
typess = SelectMultipleField("Type", choices=[("None", "None"), ("one", "one"), ("two", "two"), ("three", "three")], default=[('None', 'None')])
```

Comment: No even this is not showing choices in drop box, It's showing all choices in one box @Tobin